# how to use legend argument in scatterplot() using car package version 3

Tags: r, plot, scatter

I am new to R and trying to work through some examples in the excellent "R in Action" by Robert Kabacoff.

He makes use of the car package to make a scatterplot.  While trying the following example, I found that I was getting warnings and the plot did not match the one in the book:

```
library(car)

scatterplot(mpg ~ wt | cyl, data=mtcars, lwd=2, span=0.75, 
            main="Scatter Plot of MPG vs. Weight by # Cylinders", 
            xlab="Weight of Car (lbs / 1000)", 
            ylab="Miles Per Gallon", legend.plot=TRUE, id.method="identify", 
            labels=row.names(mtcars), boxplot="xy")
```

After some digging, I discovered that the car package has updated to version 3, and the book uses version 2.  Apparently, the argument input to most car functions has completely changed.

I did find documentation for it at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/car.pdf, but I couldn't completely follow how all the arguments work.

I got very close to getting the plot to work correctly with the following code:

```
scatterplot(mpg ~ wt | cyl, data = mtcars, pch=c(1,2,3), 
            smooth = list(smoother=loessLine, span = .75, lty.smooth=1), 
            main = "Scatter Plot of MPG vs. Weight by # Cylinders", 
            xlab = "Weight of Car (lbs/1000)", ylab = "Miles per Gallon", 
            legend = c(title="cyl", coords="topleft"), 
            id = list(method="identify"),
            showlabels = names(row.names(mtcars)), regLine=c(method=lm, lty=1))
```

But I can't seem to completely follow how to use the new arguments, especially the legend.  I can't seem to be able to plot the legend by coordinates, it only seems to work if I use the `coords="topleft"` or `coords="bottom"` type arguments.

Can anyone explain how to use the legend argument in `scatterplot()` in the car package version 3?  Specifically how to plot it in specific coordinates, and outside the plot area?

If anyone can point me to a tutorial that isn't version 2, that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I find `ggplot` a lot easier than the base `plot` functions.  You do need to set the cyl variable as a factor though.

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = as.factor(cyl), shape = as.factor(cyl))) +
 geom_point() + # plots the scatter plot
 geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F) + # plots the linear model
 geom_smooth(se = F) + # plots the loess model
 theme_minimal() # changes some of the formatting
```

[image]

I also highly recommend R for Data Science by Hadley Wickham (http://r4ds.had.co.nz/) for getting started in R. And its free!

Comment: Thanks for your reply and recommendation!  I will definitely be looking more at ggplot.  I will also check out your link.  There is so much to R that any additional information is definitely welcome.  Just curious though, are plots using the car package considered base plot functions?

Comment: So R comes with a native ploting function which is part of the `base` R package (meaning that you have access to those functions without downloading any additional packages).  They are easy to call for simple graphics (think a simple x,y scatterplot: `plot(x,y)`) but are hard for more complex charts and are also hard to make professional grade graphics.